# Why is the IPW (Inverse Probability Weighting) estimator unbiased when you know the propensity scores?

Tags: treatment-effect

The IPW estimator, for outcomes $Y_i$, treatment $T_i$, and covariates $Z_i$ is:

$$
\widehat{\text{ATE}}_{\text{IPW}} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[\frac{T_iY_i}{\widehat{\pi}(Z_i)} - \frac{(1-T_i)Y_i}{1-\widehat{\pi}(Z_i)}\right]
$$

where $\widehat{\pi}(Z_i)$ is the estimate of the propensity score.

Now, in literature it states that if the propensity scores were know, the estimator above is **unbiased**.

**My question is:** If we know the propensity scores, do we replace $\widehat{\pi}(Z_i)$ above with $\pi(Z_i)$ (the true propensity score) to obtain unbiasedness? In other words, what does it mean for the propensity scores to be **known** and how does it flow into the unbiasedness? Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the survey stuff. You can divide by the probabilities of something all you like, it isn't a Horvitz-Thompson estimator. This is observational studies, econometrics and biostat, but not survey. I am removing all the weighting and sampling tags. You are asking the third question in a row without trying to really understand the roots of the methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common situations where PS weights are known:

1. An experiment, in which case usually $\pi(Z_i)=\pi=1-\pi=\frac{1}{2}$, and your formula simplifies to a difference in means between treatment and control.
2. A computer simulation, where you know the rule by which treatment is assigned, because you coded it up yourself.

***Known* PSs allow you to average over heterogeneity to calculate average treatment effects correctly.**

Here's a simple example. Suppose men are more likely to be treated with $\pi(M) = 0.6$. Women receive treatment with probability $\pi(F)=0.4$. The untreated outcome for men is 20, while it is 10 for women. The treatment effect is the same at 5 for both genders. Suppose you sample 20 people, with 10 in each group. On average, the treated group will consists of 6 men and 4 women, with these demographics reversed in the control group.

In expectation, $$\bar Y_T= \frac{6 \cdot(20+5)+ 4 \cdot (10+5)}{10} = 21$$ and $$\bar Y_C =\frac{4\cdot 20+6 \cdot 10}{10} = 14.$$

Then naive difference in means will give you an upward-biased effect of $7 \ne 5$.

If you somehow knew the probabilities of treatment for each gender, you could scale each man's *treated* outcome down by $\frac{1}{0.6}$ and each woman's *treated* outcome up by $\frac{1}{0.4}=2.5$ to offset the composition. For *untreated* observations, you would scale each man up by $2.5$ and each women down by $1.\bar 6$.

Then your formula gives

$$ \frac{6 \cdot(20+5) \cdot \frac{1}{.6} + 4 \cdot (10+5) \cdot \frac{1}{.4} - 4\cdot 20 \cdot \frac{1}{.4}-6 \cdot 10 \cdot \frac{1}{0.6}}{20}=5,$$

which is the right answer.